# How to configure Scrapy Shell to work with BeautifulSoup parser

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I am using BeautifulSoup's default html.parser to extract data from any webpage , there are few reasons i feel it's flexible and more powerful than using XPATH/CSS selector. And i learned  Web scraping  with BeautifulSoup before Scrapy. And i couldn;t figure out a way to make Scrapy Shell use bs4 as a parser. Is it even possible ?

Comment: Is it really more flexible though? CSS is a useful thing to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply import BeautifulSoup inside the shell and give it the argument of "response.body"

```
scrapy shell https://stackoverflow.com

    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.body,'html.parser')
    soup.find('title')
```